# How to load a module inside an OCaml file?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I wish to use module `Std` inside my OCaml `.ml` file.

I tried `#load "Std"`, but the compiler complains.

How can I load a module inside OCaml?

Comment: The `#` directives are not really intended for compiled projects. This is an issue with compilation line.

Comment: Then how do I use `Std` module?

Comment: Although didierc mentions using `open`, it's considered bad practice (except in a local context). This is because one can overwrite functions that are previously declared. You should call, `ModuleA.v` in the answers case. It's clearer and in complex code you know exactly where `v` comes from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must compile the module you wish to include first, provide the location of the compiled files to compilation commands of modules depending on it, then provide it in the final compilation command line.

Let's consider for instance file `foo/moduleA.ml`:

```
let v = 1
```

and file `bar/moduleB.ml`:

```
open ModuleA
let w = v
```

The commands:

```
$ cd foo
$ ocamlc -c moduleA.ml
$ cd ..
```

will produce `moduleA.cmo` and `moduleA.cmi`. The former is the bytecode object of the module (like a `.o` file in for native object files, but containing bytecode data and text), the later is a bytecode compiled header, produced from an automatically generated `.mli` file. This bytecode header is necessary for the compiler to compile files which depend on `ModuleA`.

```
$ cd bar
$ ocamlc -I ../foo -c moduleB.ml
$ cd ..
```

will succeed in producing `moduleB.cmo`, which depends on `ModuleA`, because the previous command has been successful, and because we indicate the compiler where to look for dependancies with the `-I` command line parameter, followed by the path of the first module.

The last command below will produce a bytecode executable from both modules:

```
$ ocamlc -I foo -I bar moduleA.cmo moduleB.cmo -o prog.byte
```

The modules must be provided in that order, to let the compiler know the dependancies *first*. The `-I` parameters this time indicate where to find the `.cmo` files.

In your case, you must therefore use the `-I <location of std.cmi>` for the compilation proper phase, and `-I <location of std.cmo>` (or `std.cma`, if it is a library) for the second phase (the link phase). If you can combine both phases in one command (ie. `ocamlc -I foo foo/moduleA.ml bar/moduleB.ml -o prog.byte`), and if both `cmo` and `cmi` files are in the same directory, only one parameter will suffice.